# How do you stop processing when there's an error on the GRPC input stream?

Tags: java, protocol-buffers, grpc

Say I have a method

```proto
rpc saveFormData(stream SavedFormChunk) returns (stream SavedFormChunk) {}
```

in the server implementation

```java
public StreamObserver<SavedFormChunk> saveFormData(StreamObserver<SavedFormChunk> responseObserver) {
  return new StreamObserver<>() {
    public void onNext(SavedFormChunk chunk) {
      // say chunk was in error what do I do to stop the processing?
    }
    ...
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

About "what do I do to stop the processing" : if you want to stop the whole call (i.e. `saveFormData` rpc) then you call `responseObserver.onError()` with appropriate status. But if you just want to "stop processing" of the current current chunk received, you can just skip it and not do anything unless your client expects a `SavedFormChunk` in response for every `SavedFormChunk` it sent in the request. In that case your response message needs to be enhanced to indicate error cases so may be the response type can be `SavedFormChunkOrError` .

Answer (score 0):

It might be more clear to have types that indicate the direction in your service definition.

```
rpc saveFormData(stream SavedFormChunkRequest) returns (stream SavedFormChunkResponse) {}
```

On your request StreamObserver where you are getting request data. Add this so that if the client sends you an error you will acknowledge with an observed onComplete.

```
@Override
public void onError(Throwable t) {
    responseObserver.onCompleted();
    log.error("During form processing, requestObserver called onError", t);
}
```

To send an error back to the client. Do something like this.

```
responseObserver.onError(Status.INVALID_ARGUMENT.withDescription("The number being sent was out of range.")
                .augmentDescription("The number sent was:" + number).asRuntimeException());
```